# CSS sticker half inside a block, half outside a block

Tags: html, css

I want to have a sticker at the border of a block but the sticker "disappear" when it is outside of the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <div class="container-form">
     <div class="wrap-form">
       <div class="sticker">
         <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" />
       </div>
       <h2>Form</h2>
       <div>
        <label for="name">Name :</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">e-mail :</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="msg">Message :</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I created a codepen to put all the sources: https://codepen.io/Old_Krupnik/pen/qBENRWL

I wonder if it is possible or I have to change the div structure.

Comment: remove `overflow:hidden` from `.wrap-form` ?

Comment: That was stupid... thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the CSS property `overflow: hidden;` on your `.wrap-form` class.